# adding dynamic properties and categorizing

Tags: java, oop, jakarta-ee, web

I am trying to write a web application in java2EE, where users can post ads about anything that they are offering(a service, property, things, any thing that someone can sell), the complexity lies in categorizing these ads. there are several categories and each needs specific data (attributes). for example creating an ad about selling an apartment needs to have a fields of data about square meters , price, location, bed rooms and ... while an ad about baby sitting needs information about hours, location (there are some common fields) , fee per hour, and so on. on the other hand, the admin of this site should be able to add categories and edit their required fields.
now talking OOP, i want to have  `Class ad` and `Class category` and there is an instance of `Class category` in `Class ad`, here lies the question : how can i make `Class ad`'s attributes dependent to its `category` field? it means for example if the `category` field in `ad` is "estate" then the fields in 'ad' should be `String header`,`String description` `BigDecimal price`, `String location`, `short bedrooms` and if the `category` is "Baby Sitting!!" the fields should be `String header` , `short hours` , `BigDecimal fee`.
i know the question is not very clear, but believe me, it is complicated for myself :D 
thnx

Answer (score 0):

You should use JSON for this sort of thing, where you really can't know / describe concisely what all the facets are. Take a look at MongoDB

Comment: thnx for reply, let me take a look at that, but it seems that it is a database, and cant help in domain design issue